# jQuery Trigger onKeyup Event

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a **SELECT LIST MENU** containing products and on this menu i use onChangeevent. when you select any product, it load company name of that product.Below is the function which i used,

```
function getcompany(element) {        

        var strURL="getcompany.php?product="+element.value; 
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {   

                        element.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('companydiv')[0].innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }       
    }
```

And my html code is,

```
<select name="product" onChange="getcompany(this)">
    <option value="1" >Product1</option>
    <option value="2" >Product2</option>
    </select>
    <div class="companydiv">Product result will be shown here</div>
```

The above code work but now i want to use **jquery autocomplete** instead of **SELECT LIST MENU** because my product list containing more then 1000 products.

My Autocomplete code is,but i dont know where i'm wrong

```
<input name="product" id="product" type="text" onkeyup="getcompany(this)" />
```

Some other answers i already checked but i'm not satisfied with anyone, some of them are below

[jQuery AutoComplete Trigger Change Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431459/jquery-autocomplete-trigger-change-event)

[Jquery Autocomplete onChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759152/jquery-autocomplete-onchange-event)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-and-change-event

Comment: What is the problem? the function doesn't be called? try to use the 'select' in the autocomplete function.

Comment: @Hadas yes the function doesn't be called, & i try keypress & other events also but none of them works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find your error here, however I could make what you are trying to do. I used jquery here. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/QtC2q/4/)

Comment: your function is called when you finished typing and get out of the text box. But in my case i just enter **a** and all product containing a displayed to me & then i click on my desired one