# Fire Onchange event after AutoComplete

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, onchange

I am trying to do Autocomplete and onchange event at a time.

Means:I want to fire onchange event in a autocomplete textbox.
When i write something in the a textbox from keyboard and click outside the textbox then onchange event firing but when i select something in the from the auto suggest names onchange event is not firing.

**My HTML Code**

```
<div style="width: 34%">
   Person Name:<input id="txt0" type="text" onchange="SaveData('txt0')" class="userSearch" placeholder="Helped Person" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
function AutoComplete() {
//Autocomplete added to the textbox.
$('.userSearch').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "CTC.aspx/GetMemberName",
            data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                response(data.d)
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error occured while autocomplete');
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
});
}

function SaveData(textBoxId) {
     alert(textBoxId);
}
```

I want to fire the onchange event after selected from autocomplete.

Please Help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the change event on the autocomplete widget to achieve this.
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change

For example:

```
function AutoComplete() {
  //Autocomplete added to the textbox.
  $('.userSearch').autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
         // your ajax code
      },
      minLength: 1,
      change: function (event, ui) { SaveData(); }
  });
}
```

Comment: I want to do such that after select it will fire onchange event.

Comment: In this case, you can use the select event: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select.

Comment: One query


How i will get the txtbox id?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.userSearch').trigger('change');
```

That will trigger "change" event

Comment: Automatically it will not go to change event??

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#1').autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        "use strict";
        alert('select event called');
       },
    source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"],

    minLength: 1,
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            alert("ui.item.value: " + ui.item.value);
        } else {
            alert("ui.item.value is null");
        }
        console.log("this.value: " + this.value);
    }
});
```

This will can perform both select and change event for autocomplete.

you can also check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/74wLyd8v/

Answer (score 0):

KDRVN is correct.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

as in

```
$( "#models" ).autocomplete({source: models,  select: function( event, ui ) {alert('flippy');} });
```

Not any of these:

```
    $('#models').on('select', function() { alert('waawoo'); });
    $('#models').on('change', function() { alert('feefaa'); });
 onchange="updateModels(this)"
```