# Onclick is working, but Onchange is not working - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I've a wierd problem. The problem is onclick event is working, but onchange is not working in dropdown list. Here i use jquery to get values for dropdown from a php. What could be the problem?

Javascript:

```
<script>
     //dropdown list values
   $(function() {
   $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
   source: <?php print_r(json_encode($options)); ?> 
   });
   });

   function myfunction()
    {
        alert('hi');
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="skills">Chip ID:</label>​  
        <input id="skills" onchange="myfunction()">
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13601584/2159528

Answer (score 2):

This is because of dynamically filled drop-down, so use jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

**You shall use:**

```
$(document).on('change', '#dropdown', function(){
    alert("onChnage [using .on()]");
});
```

**Example:**

```js
$(document).on('change', '#dropdown', function(){
    alert("onChnage [using .on()]");
});



/* dynamic drop-down */
var selectField = $('#dropdown');
var empIds = [101, 102, 103];   //values
var empNames = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']; //text
var options = '';
selectField.empty();
for ( var i = 0, len = empIds.length; i < len; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + empIds[i] + '">' + empNames[i] + '</option>';
}
selectField.append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you're not dealing with a regular drop down list, you're working with a jquery plugin which is not using standard fields. If that is the same plugin I know then you want this:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
    source: <?php print_r(json_encode($options)); ?> 
   }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
     window.alert(data);//do something with the selected value
   }
});
```